# In-place conversion between row major and column major storage in three dimensions

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a program that receives three-dimensional data as flat arrays in row-major (a.k.a. "C") order as input.

I need to pass these to a library that expects the same three-dimensional data in column-major (a.k.a. "Fortran") order.
Preprocessing the arrays outside of my program is not an option.

Transforming the data while copying is no problem except for performance - there are quite a few arrays of several million elements each, and the allocation and copying is my major bottleneck - so I would like to do the transformation in-place and see if that helps.

However, I have been unable to work out the maths behind this transformation, and my googling has been less than helpful.
Is there an efficient way to perform this transformation in-place?

Comment: I stumbled over this issue once I wanted  to transpose general 2d matrices in place. It's trivial for row == col but I was surprised that it's much less trivial otherwise. I started to think about doing "cycling swaps" putting a to b, b to c, c to d until ending in the original place a. I _assumed_ there should be such cycles. Finally, I became impatient and dropped the in place idea. Another unsolved issue of that (I wouldn't call it an) idea: How to track what's already done? @peter Why I didn't mind to [google](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_matrix_transposition)?! ;-)

Comment: @Scheff I guess the reason I couldn't find anything meaningful is that it isn't easy, as I assumed - I have problems just indexing a matrix in the correct order, so expected that it was my thickness making it difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An in-place transformation (if possible) would copy all the elements of these big arrays anyway, thus it won't be cache-friendly.
Each allocation will be done once for a big array (and its subsequent long transformation) and if you have to deal with a stream of such arrays you could reuse old ones in order to avoid alloc/free repetitions.

I would simply recommend to load the data in the predictible/cache-friendly row-major order and rely on the store-buffer machinery to deal with the column-major store anti-pattern to the second (allocated) array.